# How to ignore nodemodules folder in windows?

Tags: node.js, git

I am on windows 7 and git 2.9.0 and in my project I have this in .gitignore:

```
node_modules/
node_modules/blafolder/
```

However when I go :

```
git st
```

I can see new files like :

```
new file: node_modules/blafolder/blafile.js ...
```

Basically I want to ignore the node_modules/blafolder. How can I do this in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started tracking the file(s); `.gitignore` only applies to untracked files. Stop tracking it with:

```
git reset HEAD node_modules/
```

and just the first `node_modules/` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Clean git cached for node_modules.

```
$ git rm --cached -r node_modules/
```

Now add `node_modules/blafolder` in `.gitignore` file.

```
$ git status    # see if git ignore the file
```